# Emulation mode in CUDA 3.2 with VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, cuda

I am trying to debug into my kernel code, using the device emulation mode.

[image]

However, I set break points in my kernel and it doesn't break.

```
 MatrixMultiplication_Kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(Md, Nd, Pd, Width);
```

Can anyone assist me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device emulation was removed in the 3.1 release. You can debug on Windows using [Parallel Nsight](http://www.nvidia.com/object/parallel-nsight.html), or on Linux/Mac using cuda-gdb (included with the CUDA Toolkit).

Comment: I guess you can debug if you have a device, but unfortunately it wont be possible if you don't have...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look into it or check it, but maybe the following software is an alternative or could be supportive for debugging purposes regarding cuda:

http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/

The most actual paper on the front-site is titled *"Ocelot: An Open Source Debugging and
Compilation Framework for CUDA"*. So maybe this software will help you. It seems to be under heavy development.